# Updating mongodb references errors out due to field names

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection and I'm trying to update all the entries in it to change the name of a field used to store a reference. The Query I'm using is

```
db.products.find().forEeach(function(p) {
  p.newField = p.oldField;
  db.products.save(p);
});
```

The problem is that `p.oldField` is a DBRef following the standard format of `{ "$ref": "collection", "$id": ObjectId("...")}`. When I try to run the `db.products.save(p);` Mongo returns the following error:

```
Sat Oct  1 13:00:57 uncaught exception: field names cannot start with $ [$db]
```

I'm using version 1.8.2 of the MongoDB shell. I have seen this work on an older version of the shell (1.6.5), which is where I originally came up with this query. But I can't seem to make this work on newer versions.